# Bluetooth java android info

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i have write a java code and am connected to a bluetooth device from my andoid device.
i get the several info from the main.java.
now am going to have and the second.java. for all those info of the bluetooth device that i have get from the main.java how can i get them again on the second.java?
i have to pass them with intent from the main to second.java or with other way or i have to get them again from the begin anf how can i get them?
or by just create a public function i will ask to reurn me the parameters that i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information is non persistent you can pass it in an Intent from the first to second activity.
You can also persist this info in the SQLite database and retrieve it by querying in another activity.